# How to use special characters in xfig

Tags: xfig

I am trying to write special characters in `xfig`. I am putting character code within `$` sign, as normally done in latex

> $x_1$ or $\mu$ or $\sigma$

I tried setting `Text Flags`, `Special Flag = Special`, but it didn't helped. When I export the file in `.eps` format, characters appears as it i.e. `$x_1$ or $\mu$ or $\sigma$`. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you just want to use the figure in `lyx` then you don't need to convert it to `.eps`, but just do  *Insert -> File -> External material* in lyx and specify the `.fig` file. (I haven't tried this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPS export doesn't run LaTeX, so labels are interpreted as plain text.

Run [`fig2dev`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/fig2dev1.html) to go through LaTeX:

```
fig2dev -Lpstex myfigure.fig >myfigure.pstex
fig2dev -Lpstex_t myfigure.pstex >myfigure.pstex_t
```

Then include the figure in a (La)TeX document.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\input{myfigure.pstex_t}
\end{document}
```